# Static Properties in PHP7 Anonymous Classes

Tags: php, anonymous-class

I'm working on an ORM for one of my projects, and I'm trying to avoid unnecessarily "hardcoding" the classes by using anonymous classes to extend the default functionality of the base, abstract Model.

Right now, all queries are based on a static property `$table_name` that I'd like to override in the anonymous class. However, when I try to do this, all other instances of the anonymous class receive the same value, although ideally they would get their own distinct values. I would just use a non-static property in the class instead, but there are static functions that use the static property.

The options that I see are to

1. Manually create each class and hardcode the tablename for each model
2. Rework the code to use non-static properties and parameters

Both of these solutions work, but don't seem to be as elegant as I'd like them to be. Any suggestions?

Here is an example code sample

Model class

```
<?php
class Model{
protected static $table_name;
public static function query_table(){
    [...use static::$table_name]
}
```

Extending anonymous class

```
(new class() extends TableModel {
protected static $table_name         = null;

public function setTableName($table_name) {
    static::$table_name = $table_name;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same idea and the same problem. I am nearly there but there is one problem left. The PHP engine handles my anonymous classes as the same type. Here a code to demonstrate the problem.

Test 1 causes both classes as the same type and the Ids are overridden.
Test 2 causes the second anonymous class as a different type but requires another function for each id.

```
<?php
//define('TEST',1); //Uncomment to show Test1

class Foo
{
    public static function getID()
    {
        return static::$ID;
    }
};

function getClass($classID)
{
    $class = new class extends Foo
    {
        public static $ID;
    };
    $class::$ID = $classID;
    return $class;
}

function getAnotherClass($classID)
{
    $class = new class extends Foo
    {
        public static $ID;
    };
    $class::$ID = $classID;
    return $class;
}

if (defined('TEST')) { //Test 1 - Doesn't Works
    $class1 = getClass(1); //Expected 1 - Actual 5
    $class5 = getClass(5); //Expected 5 - Actual 5
} else { //Test 2 - Work
    $class1 = getClass(1); //Expected 1 - Actual 1
    $class5 = getAnotherClass(5); //Expected 5 - Actual 5
}
print "ClassID 1: " . $class1::getID() . PHP_EOL;
print "ClassID 5: " . $class5::getID() . PHP_EOL;
print "\tBecause the types are " . (get_class($class1) === get_class($class5) ? "" : "not ") . "equal." . PHP_EOL;
```

Maybe anyone can give us a hint.

---

**Update with workaround**

I have found an ugly but working solution using `eval`.

```php
<?php

class Foo
{
    public static function getID()
    {
        return static::$ID;
    }
};

/**
 * Create a new class declaration
 *
 * @return string Returning the name of the new class.
 */
function createClass($classID): string
{
    eval('class Foo' . $classID . ' extends Foo 
    { 
        public static $ID = ' . $classID . ';
    };');

    return "Foo$classID";
}

$class1 = createClass(1);
$class5 = createClass(5);

$object1 = new $class1;
$object5 = new $class5;

print "ClassID 1 (" . get_class($object1) . "): " . $class1::getID() . PHP_EOL;
print "ClassID 5 (" . get_class($object5) . "): " . $class5::getID() . PHP_EOL;
print "\tBecause the types are " . (get_class($object1) === get_class($object5) ? "" : "not ") . "equal." . PHP_EOL;
```